# What is a term for voltage that does not involve the unit?

Tags: units

Basically the title. What is the term that means the same thing as "voltage", but does not invoke a specific unit (in this case, volts)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Electrical potential" is the term you're after here (not to be confused with electrical potential *energy* stored by opposing charges at a distance).

Comment: Often "potential difference".

Comment: Also sometimes called Electromotive Force or E.M.F.